# Улучшить быстродействие StreamReader.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных

Собственно есть много(~2GB) больших(~10MB) текстовых файлов. Каждая строка в файле это запись лога. Нужно пройти по всем файлам и по всем строками и применить `Regex(...)`.

И как и ожидалось `Regex.IsMatch()` прилично замедляет выполнение.
Но, по мимо этого профайлер показал что 44% времени тратится на `sr.ReadLine()`

вот стандартная часть кода:

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(file))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) // <-- 44% Time
    {
        //... 
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** есть способ как то быстрее читать файл построчно?

Comment: Вы можете проверить, реально ли узкое место чтение с диска или разбивка на строки следующим образом: считайте весь файл в MemoryStream, и натравите на него StreamReader (не забудьте перемотать MemoryStream в начало). И посмотрите, где теряется 44% времени — в чтении с диска в MemoryStream, или в чтение из MemoryStream построчно.

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я смог понять [отсюда](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs) и [отсюда](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs), `File.OpenText` создаёт `StreamReader` с довольно небольшим буфером для чтения. Метод `ReadLine`, в свою очередь, использует буфер именно этого размера.

Поэтому первым делом я бы попробовал создать `FileStream` и `StreamReader` поверх него, задав размер буфера побольше:

```
const int bufferSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024; // 16Mb

FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize, FileOptions.SequentialScan);

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Обращение к файловой системе — это традиционное узкое место многих приложений. В отличие от C++, где есть нюансы, в C# метод `ReadLine` заметно не оптимизируется. Можете попробовать `FileOptions.SequentialScan`, но на многое не рассчитывайте.

Вам поможет только SSD.

Comment: `File.OpenText` уже это делает (создаёт `StreamReader`, который открывает `FileStream` с опцией `FileOptions.SequentialScan`).

Answer (score 1):

Если воспользоваться winapi, то можно присобачить чтение через memory mapped file, что, теоретически, должно сильно повысить производительность.

Ещё желательно правильно выставить набор флагов для открытия файла.

Comment: Вы меряли? Каким образом отображение файла в память может ускорить чтение, если нужно прокрутить блин абсолютно такое же количество раз?

Comment: @Discord, вообще-то оно для этого специально предназначено. И в случае с чтением через winapi на плюсах, кто-то этот пример показывал, что оно в разы быстрее. Быстрее должно быть за счёт того, что windows сам параллельно заранее подгружает файл в память и когда программа выполняет чтение, она просто берёт нужное из памяти, а не инициирует чтение с диска, завершения которого ещё надо дождаться. Но если есть желание замерить время и сравнить, то буду рад увидеть результаты.

Comment: Хм.. @Discord, а не получится ли то же самое, если использовать async и разделить чтение и обработку? А ещё лучше, растащить их по разным потокам?

Comment: А вот разделение уже похоже на эффективную стратегию, если на CPU приходится только половина времени. Правда async/await добавляет тормозов, надо мерять.